# How do I get rid of blury pixels in Gtkmm?

Tags: c++, pixel, cairo, gtkmm

When I draw a picture and zoom way in, GTKmm (or Cairo I suppose) blends the pixels together to make a nice smooth image. I really hate that. It's terrible for debugging. I want to see clear crisp pixels with sharp images. I want to see nice little squares. So how do I turn off the cool blendy feature?

Here is how I paint the image.

```
Gdk::Cairo::set_source_pixbuf(cairoContext, tile->tileImage, tile->x, tile->y);
cairoContext->paint();
```

Also tried fill to see if it was any different.

```
Gdk::Cairo::set_source_pixbuf(cairoContext, tile->tileImage, tile->x, tile->y);
cairoContext->rectangle(tile->x, tile->y, tile->tileImage->get_width(), tile->tileImage->get_height());
cairoContext->fill();
```

It wasn't.

Edit:
This doesn't work:

```
cairoContext->set_antialias(Cairo::Antialias::ANTIALIAS_NONE);
```

Comment: When you say "zoom way in", presumably you are scaling the image somehow.  It sounds like you want to use nearest-neighbor interpolation, but some other form of interpolation is being used instead.  You'll need to identify what function/library you are using to do the scaling, and then read its documentation to figure out how to change the type of interpolation.

Comment: Scaling is done with:
cairoContext->scale(this->scale, this->scale);

Comment: The documentation for scale is: "Modifies the current transformation matrix (CTM) by scaling the X and Y user-space axes by sx and sy respectively. The scaling of the axes takes place after any existing transformation of user space."
Please point out the part that talks about interpolation. I seemed to have missed it.

Comment: https://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-pattern-t.html#cairo-filter-t

Comment: Scaling (at least up-scaling) always involves some type of interpolation.  In cairo land, it seems that different interpolation types are called filters.  Look up the documentation for cairo_filter_t (link in previous comment), or refer to Uli's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a `NEAREST` filter on the pattern. I'm not sure about the C++ API for this, but in C I would do the following (after the call to `set_source_pixbuf`):

```
cairo_pattern_set_filter(cairo_get_source(cr), CAIRO_FILTER_NEAREST);
```

Comment: cairo_pattern_set_filter?

Comment: You are right. Sorry for missing the "pattern" part.

Comment: Thanks. There doesn't appear to be a cairomm wrapper for this function, or at least I couldn't find it. To use it I had to change it a bit: `cairo_pattern_set_filter(cairo_get_source(cairoContext->cobj()), CAIRO_FILTER_NEAREST);`

Comment: This craters the performance when zoomed out though. I'll have to use it conditionally when scale is greater than one. Also, I switched to CAIRO_FILTER_FAST.